# What's the use of this section in RP window panel?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In main menu, top right corner, there's a RP icon to click:

[image]

After clicking it, then this window panel open (my doubt):

[image]

It contains:

> 2 graffiti bottle, 1 parachute trail and RP badge.

What's the use of this section in RP window panel?